# View HTTP headers in Safari

Tags: safari, http-headers

In Safari 10 web browser on Mac OS X Sierra and with the Web Inspector turned on, I go visit a public website such as google.com.

How does one view HTTP headers in Safari on macOS?

Comment: This works great but how do I modify an HTTP header value?

Answer (score 55, accepted):

(Putting the full solution here so people who haven't got as far as enabling the web inspector will see it.)

First ensure that the `Develop` menu is enabled: in the `Advanced` pane in Safari Preferences (`Cmd + ,`) select "Show Develop menu in menu bar".

Then, from the `Develop` menu select `Show Page Resources` (`Cmd + Alt + A`). Then, in the top right corner of the view, just under the tab bar, there is a button to "Show the details sidebar" (`Cmd + Alt + 0`). Click it.

Then you can select each resource from the left sidebar and the headers will appear in the right sidebar. You may need to refresh the page to see them initially.

Comment: Worth noting Safari does not show you all the headers OR the raw headers. It is a stripped down selection of headers you see.