# How to view cookies in safari 10?

Tags: macos, cookies, safari

These are the approaches I have tried:

1. [View HTTP headers in Safari 10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39760367/view-http-headers-in-safari-10), but the cookies is not showed there
2. I can find `Cookies` section under `Storage` Tab, but the Cookies are displayed in a table.
   [image]

I would like to view the Cookies in a string rather than a table, is there any way except using another browser?

Answer (score 2):

Go to the Console<sup>*</sup> tab. Type

```
document.cookie
```

[which shows all cookies for this location](https://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-HTML/html.html#ID-8747038).

---

`*`: to access the console, (credit @Geoff Crompton)

> if [you] have the developer menu enabled, [you] can go to the `Develop` menu, choose `Show Web Inspector`, and in the bottom of the new window type `document.cookie` to see the cookies for the current website

Comment: I don't think Mozilla documentation will help with this question about the Safari browser.

Comment: @GeoffCrompton: did you try it? MDN most often describes the standard. If you object to this, it has been updated to link to w3.

Comment: Please let me apologise @serv-inc. I hadn't tried it. But now that I have, I can see that in Safari (version 13.0.4), if I have the developer menu enabled, I can go to the Develop menu, choose Show Web Inspector, and in the bottom of the new window type "document.cookie" to see the cookies for the current website.

Comment: Apology accepted @GeoffCrompton. Your step-by-step has been included in this answer (feel free to create your own and reply if you object) I was not aware that the steps to reproduce this needed more details.

Answer (score 2):

Safari `Version 14.0.3 (16610.4.3.1.4)`

The `Develop` menu of Safari adds a variety of additional features to the web browser on the Mac, including the inspector and error consoles, javascript debugging tools, the ability to disable various page elements, enable the `Do Not Track` feature, use WebGL acceleration, and it offers a simple way to change the browsers user agent.

[image]

Develop menu in Safari:

1. Pull down the `Safari` menu and choose `Preferences`
2. Click on the `Advanced` tab
3. Check the box next to `Show Develop menu in menu bar`
4. Close `Preferences`, the `Develop` menu will now be visible between `Bookmarks` and `Window` menus

Comment: My `Storage` was hidden. Right click on that panel to enable/disable.

Comment: Same as @A.D. , I thought I was going crazy but the storage tab was hidden.

Comment: It is important that the answer helped you get to the desired step, both him and you. Good luck

Answer (score 1):

It will require a little fiddling, but there is a Python script here http://www.securitylearn.net/2012/10/27/cookies-binarycookies-reader/ that can dump the Binary Cookie format (located in ~/Library/Cookies/).